# preg_match doesn't capture the content

Tags: php, preg-match, match, preg-match-all

what is wrong with my preg_match ?

```
preg_match('numVar("XYZ-(.*)");',$var,$results);
```

I want to get all the ***CONTENT*** from here:

numVar("XYZ-***CONTENT***");

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is PHP? If so there are three problems with your code.

1. PHP's PCRE functions require that regular expressions be formatted with a delimiter. The usual delimiter is `/`, but you can use any matching pair you want.
2. You did not escape your parentheses in your regular expression, so you're not matching a `(` character but creating a RE group.
3. You should use non-greedy matching in your RE. Otherwise a string like `numVar("XYZ-CONTENT1");numVar("XYZ-CONTENT2");` will match *both*, and your "content" group will be `CONTENT1");numVar("XYZ-CONTENT2`.

Try this:

```
$var = 'numVar("XYZ-CONTENT");';
preg_match('/numVar\("XYZ-(.*?)"\);/',$var,$results);

var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste your example string into http://txt2re.com and look at the PHP result.

It will show that you need to escape characters that have special meaning to the regex engine (such as the parentheses).

Comment: Cool site - will have to remember that one.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape some chars:

```
preg_match('numVar\("XYZ-(.*)"\);',$var,$results);
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work, I get: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: Actually you have to escape even more chars, namely the backslashes themselves. Also the pattern itself is missing start/end delimiters, e.g. `/`

Comment: Ok, but when I add `/` on the beginning & end it returns no results

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/XYZ\-(.+)\b/", $string, $result);
print_r($result[0]); // full matches ie XYZ-CONTENT
print_r($result[1]); // matches in the first paren set (.*)
```

Comment: Whole structure is important - numVar("XYZ-